# Ruby on Rails - undefined method `persisted?' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook

I'm new to ruby on rails and i'm trying to use oauth with Facebook but i'm getting this error: `undefined method 'persisted?' for nil:NilClass`. This happens when ever I try to sign in with Facebook. Any ideas why?

The model:

`usuarios.rb`

```
class Usuario < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :c    onfirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  devise :omniauthable, omniauth_providers: [:facebook]

  def self.find_or_create_by_omniauth(auth)
    usuario = Usuario.where(provider: auth[:provider], uid: [:uid]).first
    return usuario if usuario

    usuario = Usuario.create[
        nombre: auth[:nombre],
        apellido: auth[:apellido],
        username: auth[:username],
        email: auth[:email],
        uid: auth[:uid],
        prvider: auth[:provider],
        password: Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
    ]


  end

end
```

The controller

`omniauth_callback_controller.rb`

```
class OmniauthCallbacksController < ApplicationController
    def facebook
        auth = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
          data = {
          nombre: auth.info.first_name,
          apellido: auth.info.last_name,
          username: auth.info.nickname,
          email: auth.info.email,
          provider: auth.provider,
          uid: auth.uid
        }
        @usuario = Usuario.find_or_create_by_omniauth(data)

        if @usuario.persisted?
          sign_in_and_redirect @usuario, event: :authentication
        else
          session[:omniauth_errors] = @usuario.errors.full_messages.to_sentence unless @usuario.save

          session[:omniauth_data] = data

          redirect_to new_usuario_registration_url
      end
  end

  def failure
      redirect_to new_usuario_registration_url
  end

end
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Note that you also have a typo in`Usuario.create` at this line: `prvider: auth[:provider],` - it should be `provider: auth[:provider],`, with an `o`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting nil is because you are using brackets instead of parens.

```
# creates two things
Thing.create [{ name: foo }, { name: bar}]
# => nil
```

When you do `Usuario.create[nombre: auth[:nombre],...` you are actually passing an array - ActiveRecord will try to make several records and will always return nil.

Also beside the fact that your code is riddled with typos [ActiveRecord actually provides a few methods to do this with a lot less fuss](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#find-or-build-a-new-object):

```
.first_or_create(attributes, &block) # when you don't want duplicates
.first_or_inialize(attributes, &block) # very useful for updates
```

You should also note that the `request.env["omniauth.auth"]` hash created by omniauth follows the [Auth Hash Schema](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/wiki/Auth-Hash-Schema) - you are not using the right keys so many of the attributes in your model will end up as nil.

So lets refactor `.find_or_create_by_omniauth`:

```
def self.find_or_create_by_omniauth(auth)
  self.where(auth.slice(:uid, :provider))
    # see the auth hash schema for available keys
    .create_with(auth[:info].slice(:email)) 
    .first_or_create do |user|
      user.nombre = auth[:nombre] # will most likely be nil!
      user.apellido = auth[:apellido] # will most likely be nil!
      user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
    end
end
```

`Hash#slice` is a cool ActiveSupport method that lets you copy a hash but only with the desired keys - without manually copying it:

```
hash = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
{ a: hash[:a], c: hash[:c] } # wow, much typing, such boring
hash.slice(:a,:c)

# => { a: 1, c: 3}
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped me solve my problem. I come from a PHP background so all this is preatty new to me. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

#### The problem is that you use `create[]` instead of `create()`.

## What is going on really

`ARSubClass.create[foo: 1, bar: 2, baz: 3]` is equal to 
`ARSubClass.create[ {foo: 1, bar: 2, baz: 3} ]` 

`ARSubClass.create` try to create an instance of `ARSubClass`, but it fails,
 because of validations I guess and returns non persisted record. 
 And then you call method `[]` on it with one parameter `{foo: 1, bar: 2, baz: 3}` 
 `instance[{foo: 1, bar: 2, baz: 3}] => nil`.

### The solution is to use `create` like this `create(...)`.

More "RailsWay" approach will be to use [find_or_create_by](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/Relation/find_or_create_by) to implement `find_or_create_by_omniauth`. 
Notice that if you pass a block to `find_or_create_by` it will be evaluated only in `create` case.

#### Aditional notes:

- Instead of `where(foo: 'baz', bar: 'mar').first`,
   use `find_by(foo: 'baz', bar: 'mar')`
- In the controller don't set `@usuario` as instance variable(with `@` prefix) 
   if you not going to use it in some view. 
  Just set it to variable `usuario = ...` and it scope will be only in the current method.

Answer (score 0):

Your `find_or_create_by_omniauth` method is returning `nil` when it creates a new Usuario. A rails method returns the last statement in the method, and when you create a record, it returns nil. You need to just add `usuario` at the end of your method like:

```
def self.find_or_create_by_omniauth(auth)
    usuario = Usuario.where(provider: auth[:provider], uid: [:uid]).first
    return usuario if usuario

    usuario = Usuario.create[
        nombre: auth[:nombre],
        apellido: auth[:apellido],
        username: auth[:username],
        email: auth[:email],
        uid: auth[:uid],
        prvider: auth[:provider],
        password: Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
    ]

    usuario
  end
```

Comment: Does not solve the issue. In Ruby the last value in the method (not the last statement!) is implicitly returned anyways. The real reason he is getting nil is because he is using brackets instead of parens. If you do `Usuario.create(email: 'test@example.com')` it returns the record. However create also lets you create multiple records at once by passing an array of hashes - but the return value is nil. `Usuario.create[ foo: 'bar' ... ]`  is treated as an array of hashes.

Comment: Yes, the last line/last value/last statement is what is returned from a method. Because he is creating the method last (using brackets), it's returning nil. Thus, nil is returned. :)